# ovftool import succeeds but VM is not able to be found

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, import, ovf

So I am importing a VM using the following command:

```
ovftool.exe --name="test_VM2" --datastore="vsanDatastore" C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\VM_Exports\test_server.ova "administrator@vcenter.com/TEST/host/GPU Cluster"
Opening OVA source: C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\VM_Exports\test_server.ova
The manifest validates
Opening VMX target: administrator@vcenter.com/TEST/host/GPU Cluster
Writing VMX file: administrator@vcenter.com/TEST/host/GPU Cluster\test_VM2\test_VM2.vmx
Transfer Completed
Completed successfully
```

When I login to vcenter, I am unable to find nay VMs with a name of "test_vm2". Am I importing this incorrectly? If I attempt again it states the "File already exists" so its uploading something. Any thought on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Command should have been:

```
ovftool.exe --name="test_VM2" --datastore="vsanDatastore" C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\VM_Exports\test_server.ova "vi://administrator@vcenter.com/TEST/host/GPU Cluster"
```